# How to print control characters with escape sequences?

Tags: shell, escape-characters, printf

I have defined the color red using tput

```
red=$(tput setaf 1)
```

to colorize warnings in my program. This works fine:

```
printf '%sfail\n' "$red"
# prints 'fail' in red
```

But on one occasion I would like to print out the escape sequence as-is, something like:

\E[31mfail

How would I do this? I know printf has a `%q` flag but it escape others stuff I don't want to.

Comment: Is it  just the ESC (0x1b) character you want to convert to `\E`, or other control characters?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sounds like you want the opposite of printing them literally, you want those escape characters converted to a printable descriptive form like `\E` or `\033`, `^[`...

If it's just the ESC (0x1b) character you want to convert to `\E`, then with `ksh93`, `zsh` or `bash` (typically, the same ones that also support that non-standard `%q`), you can do:

```
printf '%s\n' "${red//$'\e'/\\E}"
```

Or pipe to `sed $'s/\e/\\\\E/g'`

For a more generic approach at converting non-graphical characters, you can use:

```
$ printf %s "$red" | od -A n -vt c # POSIX
 033   [   3   1   m
$ printf %s "$red" | sed -n l # POSIX
\033[31m$
$ printf '%s\n' "${(qqqq)red}" # zsh
$'\033[31m'
$ printf '%s\n' "$red" | cat -vt # some cat implementations
^[[31m
$ printf %s "$red" | uconv -x ':: [:Cc:]; ::Hex;' # ICU tools
\u001B[31m
$ printf %s "$red" | uconv -x ':: [:Cc:]; ::Name;' # ICU tools
\N{<control-001B>}[31m
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `od`, `hexdump`, `xxd`, or similar to print binary data in human-readable form.  For example:

```
$ tput setaf 1 | od -c
0000000 033   [   3   1   m
0000005
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `printf` directly, eg

```
printf "\033[31mfail"
```